# Discord command: args.join is not a function

Tags: node.js, command, discord.js, embed, webhooks

I want that my bot sends a webhook embed to a discord channel, this is my code but I don't know how to solve this error

`TypeError: args.join is not a function`

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const { WebhookClient, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = class reportCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'report',
      group: 'help',
      memberName: 'report',
      description: 'Report some bug about me.',
    });
  }
  
    async run (client, message, args) { 
      const wc = new WebhookClient('0000000000000', '000000000000')
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("this is an embed")
          .setColor('GREEN')
          .setTimestamp()
          .setDescription(args.join(" "))
  wc.send({
      username : message.author.tag,
      avatarURL : message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic : true }),
      embeds : [embed]
  })
  }
}
```

Btw, i already tried this

```
args: [
        {
          key: 'reason',
          prompt:
            'Whats your problem?',
          type: 'string'
        },
]

Embed
.setDescription(reason)
```

but it still doesn't work, I get another one in the description of the embed message `undefined` and if it is not that one it will probably be `displayAvatarURL`, so I don't really know what to do or how to fix it, because if I remove `displayAvatarURL` the message will still be `indefinied`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/Command?scrollTo=run). The `Command.run()` method's arguments are as follows---`message`, `args`, `fromPattern` and `result` in that order (`result` being optional)

```js
   run(message, args, fromPattern [,result])
```

You're actually trying to access the `join()` method of the third argument---`fromPattern`--- which it doesn't have since `fromPattern` is a **boolean** (true/false) variable and `join()` is an **array** method

Comment: Join is an array method

Comment: @Elitezen oops. sorry typo. thanks for pointing it out